# Finding index from Select query in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to find the `index` at which the difference between two properties in a `List<>` is `max`? Currently, I'm finding the `max` using this `LINQ` query below:

```
var result = link.Select(x => Math.Abs(x.Prop1 - x.Prop2)).Max();
```

How can I get the index ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var result = 
     link.Select((x, i) => new { value = Math.Abs(x.Prop1 - x.Prop2), index = i })
          .OrderByDescending(x=>x.value)
          .FirstOrDefault();

var indexValue = result?.index;
var maxValue = result?.value;
```

Here this is working.

Comment: Thanks. So a combination of `OrderByDescending` and `First` replaced `Max()`? Any specific reason why I couldn't find index using `Max` ?

Comment: @hello The object which return in the select should inherit IComparable and you should build internal logic how you will take Max of him, max of what. After that you can call index of this object. But this will too much work for nothing.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a large amount of data, you might get concerned about those methods creating 2 extra sets of data before you get the result.  You could use a from statement and generate only one extra set:

```
int index = (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, link.Count)
             orderby Math.Abs(link.Prop1 - link.Prop2)
             select new { index = i, value = link[i] }).First().index;
```

Or use a plain for loop and not create any extra sets:

```
int max = 0;
int indx = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < link.Count;i++)
{
    int temp = Math.Abs(link.Prop1 - link.Prop2);
    if (temp > max)
    {
        max = temp;
        indx = i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Following is the working version using `Max` which needs implementation of `Icomparable<T>` (**code is created using LinqPad, it contains some test data for verification**)

```
void Main()
{
    List<Test> link = Test.FetchList();

    var result = link.Select((x, i) => new { x.Prop1, x.Prop2, index = i })
                     .Max(y => new Result {value = Math.Abs(y.Prop1 - y.Prop2), index = y.index});

    result.Dump(); // In this case result would be index 2

}

public class Test
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set;}

    public int Prop2 { get; set;}

    public static List<Test> FetchList()
    {
      var returnList = new List<Test>();

        returnList.Add(new Test { Prop1 = 1, Prop2 = -5});
        returnList.Add(new Test { Prop1 = 2, Prop2 = -5});
        returnList.Add(new Test { Prop1 = 1, Prop2 = -9});
        returnList.Add(new Test { Prop1 = 3, Prop2 = -2});
        returnList.Add(new Test { Prop1 = 21, Prop2 = 15});

      return (returnList);
    }

}

public class Result : IComparable<Result>
{
    public int value { get; set; }

    public int index { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Result other)
    {
       return (value - other.value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var r =  link
        .Select((x,idx)=>new{v = x, idx})
        .OrderBy(x=>Math.Abs(x.v.Prop2 - x.v.Prop1))
        .FirstOrDefault();

return r !=null ? r.idx : -1;
```